# Divide polygons based on internal differences in shape using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3, splitting, shape-area

For my research, I'm trying to assess where we could potentially plant small, medium and large trees (with respectively 5m², 20m² and 45m² soil area needed). Besides patch size, also patch shape is an important factor. It could be that we have a patch of 20m² (=large enough for 1 medium tree), but it has a complete strip-like shape (= dimensions 1m x 20m) and is thus unsuitable for a medium tree because we assume that the roots won't be able to reach the end of the patch. Therefore, a patch may have a maximal value of 1.2 for the patch fractal dimension index (this is a value between 1 and 2, where 1 is a very simple shape like a square and 2 a very complex shape like a line; [image]).

The goal is to do this in an urban territory and as you can imagine, plant-able patches have very complex shapes. An example of such a shape is shown in the figure below.

[image]

The main issue is that this polygon provides space for 1-2 medium size trees in the green circle, and for some small trees in the black circle. However, I'm struggling in developing an algorithm that divides the polygon automatically into (in this case) two patches: 1 for the medium trees and 1 for the small trees...

I work in QGIS 3, so I'm rather looking for an answer that can be executed by PyQGIS

Comment: If you request some sort of code or workflow it is best to already post some sort of psuedo code or at least some lines you have tried to solve the problem at hand.

Comment: what shape *can* a tree's roots have? Do you assume circular? This looks likely to be one of those "no closed form solution" problems that will require trial and error and lots of sampling and resampling to get a *good* solution, with the absolute best solution being computationally intractable.

Comment: @MarcM, at this point, I'm stuck at the conceptual point of tackling this problem, so I do not have any code yet to share...

Comment: @Spacedman, in my research, roots do not have a specific shape. The only constraint is the minimum area needed for a small/ medium/ large tree and the corresponding shape index for that specific patch